# Sony XPeria Arc: How force DNS resolution with a specific host?

Tags: adb, dns

I've made my website and it can be accessed only through specific domain name.

`http://my.specific.domain.name`.

And of course, you have to change your `/etc/hosts` configuration and add

```
my.specific.domain.name 192.222.222.222
```

to make it look to the right IP.

Any idea how to do this on a Sony XPeria Arc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a rooted phone for this. First get the `/hosts` file:

```
adb pull /system/etc/hosts
```

This copies it into your current working directory. Now make your changes. (If you're not using a UNIX system make sure that you use something that supports UNIX newlines, like Notepad++, Sublime Text, Gedit etc.)

Then we need to send it back to the device with:

```
adb remount
adb push hosts /system/etc/hosts
```

The first line remounts your `/system` partiton so you can write to, and the second pushes it back. Now reboot your device. As you already have a terminal open just type:

```
adb reboot
```

Comment: What is "`adb`"  and how can I `root` my phone?

Comment: @OlivierPons `abd` is short for `android debug bridge`. It's a tool for developers to interact with phones using a computer. It can be download  from [here](http://developer.android.com/index.html). Regarding rooting, look [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/how-do-i-root-my-device). Xda-developers usually has the most up to date guides for rooting.